# Behaviour of a function in differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following question, which is says that:
$$y′−(1/3)y=e−t, y(0)=l,$$
and it says that y goes to zero as t goes to infinity if $l=−3/4$.

How is that?

Comment: Did you find the solution of this Cauchy problem?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy No , i dont know how it conclude the last statment !

Answer (score 2):

If we solve the DEQ:

$$y' - \dfrac{1}{3} y = e^{-t}, y(0) = L,$$

we arrive at:

$$y(t) = \left(L+\frac{3}{4}\right) e^{t/3}-\frac{3}{4}e^{-t}$$

We now want the limit of $y(t)$ to go zero as $t \to \infty$.

We need for that positive exponential term to go away for this, so what conclusion can be drawn about the value $L$?

$$L = -\dfrac{3}{4}$$